# cron job not started daily

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I have a script in /etc/cron.daily/backup.sh file is allowed to execute and run but do not start happening, I read the manual and used the search but not mastered decision.

```
ls -l /etc/cron.daily/
total 52
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8686 2009-04-17 10:27 apt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 314 2009-02-10 19:45 aptitude
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 103 2011-05-22 19:08 backup.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 502 2008-11-05 03:43 bsdmainutils
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 89 2009-01-27 00:55 logrotate
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 954 2009-03-19 16:17 man-db
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 646 2008-11-05 03:37 mlocate
```

Comment: is the script executable? (ls -l)

Comment: does it start with the correct #! line?  and do you specify the full path to the shell you're using, e.g. #!/bin/bash ?

Comment: @arruah Check your root Email to see if there are any errors emailed to you! e.g.  `sudo more /var/spool/mail/root` or if that file is very large, just tail the last couple of hundred line like this: `sudo tail -100  /var/spool/mail/root`

Comment: your `/etc/cron.deny` file should be empty, and your `/etc/cron.allow` file should not exist, unless you really want to use those for fine-granular permissions on who can run what

Answer (score 2):

The cron job filename can't have a period in it on certain ubuntus.  See [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto).  Particularly, this quote within:

> Although the directories contain periods in their names, run-parts
>   will not accept a file name containing a period and will fail silently
>   when encountering them

Properly, this is a problem with run-parts, which the ubuntu cron runs, and not with cron itself.  Still, it's what bit me.

Comment: is that only on Ubuntu? I'm on Fedora and  in fact my /etc/cron.daily/ has files with a period in them -- e.g. named something.cron

Comment: If the fedora is using the same `run-parts` binary, then likely.  One could peek inside the actual crontab to see what it does to execute the contents of `/etc/cron.*`, or just try to reproduce with one in cron.hourly (perhaps echo the date to some file.)

Comment: i don't know about working on Fedora but in Ubuntu is not working

Comment: yes, it's using `/usr/bin/run-parts` . cheez - I really prefer the old way to put things directly into the crontab :-P

Comment: How did you test?  I assume you renamed the file to drop the `.sh`, but how did you test the firing of the job?  Fiddling with your clock might not do it.  If I were you, I'd test by fetching the actual command used from within the crontab, since cron itself (as others have pointed out) is probably not the problem.

Comment: you could also add two lines to your script, which `touch` a file when the script starts and when the script stops.. then you can pretty easily check if these files have new or old time-stamps

Answer (score 0):

pls check:

1a) is the script executable and has correct owner/group settings?

1b) does it start with the correct #! line? and do you specify the full path to the shell you're using, 
e.g. #!/bin/bash ?

2) does the script generate an error while being executed?
e.g. can you write to a log file from it, and do you see the log messages?

also: check in the email inbox of the user who owns the crontab -- errors are emailed to the user / e.g. root

what does the output of `ls -l /etc/cron.daily/` look like? can you post that?

---

NOTE:

you can always create a crontab entry for this yourself, outside of those cron.xxx directory structure ;-)

See: `man 5 crontab`

```
 10 1 * * * /somewhere/backup.sh >> /somewhere/backup.log 2>&1
```

this has the advantage that you get to pick the exact time when it runs (e.g. 1:10am here),  and you can redirect STRERR and STDOUT to append to a log file for that particular script

For testing purposes you could run it ever 10 minutes, like this:

```
 0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * /somewhere/backup.sh >> /somewhere/backup.log 2>&1
```

do `touch /somewhere/backup.log` to make sure it exists

Comment: manually this script run fine, no errors. File is executable.

Comment: I know about this way of solving problems, but that in fact there is a special folder, I wonder why it does not work this way.

Comment: very odd. did you try to rename the script without the .sh , like @phs suggested?

Comment: looking at your script again, you're doing an rsync... perhaps root does not have the same permissions (e.g. .ssh key) as when you are running it manually?   It could be that it tries to wait for a password, and that's why you don't see it processing